# gridview editing without using datasource control

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, gridview

I am looking for some examples for gridview for common tasks like displaying, editing, deleting, paging, sorting, batch updates etc, but WITHOUT using any datasource controls. I would like to bind the data in the code to custom object collection. all the samples I found on the web so far use some data source control, I think Enterprise applications shouldn't be using this pattern. objects in my solution have only business logic and no data access code. instead I use manager objects to do this. 
    if you have any examples of gridview that performs the common tasks without using any data source control, can you please share them? that would be very helpful. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Editable GridView in ASP.NET 2.0](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/Editable_GridView.aspx)

[Sorting a GridView Bound to a Custom Data Object](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/e07f0f1a-4243-4050-8278-00d32b2e5121/aspnet--sorting-a-gridv.aspx)

Comment: thanks. that was helpful. one difference is that it uses data adapters which I can replace with my own data access classes. interested to know if batch updates can also be done without using the data source control